# Why registered users are not showing inside my AspNetUsers table, inside asp.net core web application

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I have created an asp.net MVC core web application, and i chose "Individual User" Accounts, as follow:-

[image]

Now when i access the home page >> click on Register >> enter the username & password & confirm password >> click on Register >> i will get this message:-

[image]

And the user did not get added inside the AspNetUsers database table:-

[image]

Any idea what can be causing this? why i am unable to register the users?

Answer (score 0):

Disable the email sender for activation. I think it fails to create when sending email fails.

Comment: can you advice how i can disable this?

Comment: Hi @test test,If you want to disable the email sender for activation,just remove:`options.SignIn.RequireConfirmedAccount = true;`.Although you do not click the `confirm your account`,it could also create the user,but the user could not login successfully.So you still needs to provide some code to share with us how did you register the user and how did you configure the startup.cs.

Comment: @Tajuddin i am using the built-in registration, i did not add any code to register the users